# Bilinear forms on finite-dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

Reading *Quadratic functions in geometry, topology, and M-theory* by M. J. Hopkins and I. Singer (https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1143642908), I reckon some unclarity on p. 410:

> Suppose that $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ of finite dimension, and $q_V:V→\mathbb{Q}$ is a quadratic function (not necessarily even) whose underlying bilinear form $B(x, y)=q_V(x+y)−q_V(x)−q_V(y)$ is non-degenerate. **One easily checks that $q_V(x)−q_V(−x)$ is linear**, and so there exists a unique $λ∈V$ with $q_V(x)−q_V(−x)=−B(λ, x)$.

**EDIT** *1)* $q_V(x)−q_V(−x)$ is linear, as pointed out below. **EDIT**

*2)* How to achieve such a $\lambda$ (possibly without using linearity), maybe by exploiting non-degeneracy of $B$?

Comment: It is linear, the quadratic terms cancel.

Comment: @PaulK You're right! The zero map is obviously linear.

Comment: What is your definition of non-degenerate bilinear form? Because usually this would just follow from definition (some authors make a distinction between non-degenerate and regular, which disappears for finite-dimensional vector spaces).

Comment: @CaptainLama For a non-degenerate bilinear form, the induced map $\psi: V \rightarrow \Hom(V, \mathbb{Q})$, defined by$\(psi(v))(v'):=B(v,v')$, is an isomorphism. Is this what you had in mind? If so, can you elaborate on how it follows from the definition?

Comment: $q_V(x) - q_V(-x)$ is linear and thus in $\operatorname{Hom}(V, \mathbb{Q})$. Since the map $\psi$ you mention is an isomorphism, there is some $\lambda$ with $\psi(\lambda)(x) = q_V(x) - q_V(-x)$.